# Find a file that contains a certain string and rename it but keep extension

Tags: powershell, scripting, rename, wildcard

I'm trying to find two files called:

```
bitbucket_20181013.bak
bitbucket_20181013-237823-23.tar
```

I'm trying to find these files using the date extension "20181013" and I want to rename it to "{todaysDate}_bitbucket_backup.{ext}"

So far I have the following:

```
$date = [DateTime]::Nw.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
$file = "*$date*"
$name = "$($date)_Bitbucket_Backup"

Get-ChildItem -Path Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\KERGRINFS4\Seagate\Bitbucket_Backups\backups |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -like $file } |
    %{ Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName "$name + $_.extension" }
```

But it doesn't work, it returns: "20181014_Bitbucket_Backup + bitbucket_20181014.bak.extension" instead of "20181014_Bitbucket_Backup.bak"

Comment: _"But it doesn't work as I would expect it."_ - what's unexpected and what do you expect?

Comment: Sorry, updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$_.extension` to `$($_.extension)`.

```
"$_.extension"    # Give me string that is $_, then add the literal string .extension to it
"$($_.extension)" # evaluate the expression $_.extension, then give me the results of that as a string.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you, but if got you right, you want to change files contains the string '20181013' and rename it to todays date using the `yyyyMMdd` date format?

You can use `String.Replace` and `Rename-Item` in one command to make the code more readable as well, try that:

```
$Path = 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\KERGRINFS4\Seagate\Bitbucket_Backups\backups'
$OldString = 'bitbucket_20181013'
$NewString = "{0}_Bitbucket_Backup" -f [datetime]::now.tostring("yyyyMMdd") 

Get-ChildItem $Path | ? {$_.Name -match $OldString} | 
% {Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName ($_.Name.Replace($OldString,$NewString)) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't really need to embed variables when defining "new name". I'd also suggest to be more consistent with aliases.

```
ls | where { $_.Name -like $file } | foreach { ren $_.FullName -NewName ($name + $_.extension) }
```